# Hibernate's first level cache not working for boolean type?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, caching, transactional

I have a spring `@Transactional` read-only service that spans several calls to a `JpaRepository` with a method using a native query  that returns a `boolean`. The query is heavy and  when checking logs looks like is executed several times with same parameters.
Shouldn't be only called once? Does first-level cache not working when using Spring Transactions? is it because it's returning a `boolean` instead of an `@Entity`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First level cache works only for results which **EntityManagers can manage, which are Entities.** (or Session within Hibernate)

If you would like to cache other objects or simple types I'd suggest to use @Cacheable annotation with some cache provider, for example **EhCache** [LINK](https://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-caching-and-ehcache-example/)

**EDIT:**

Your own queries aren't part of first level cache mechanism. Only simple operation like, persist, merge, update etc. can use it. For more information check this article [LINK](http://www.kubrynski.com/2017/04/understanding-jpa-l1-caching.html)